# Error compiling OpenCV, fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory

Tags: opencv, gcc, cmake

I'm trying to compile OpenCV. I've tried the master branch (which is currently on commit dc9602e) and version/tag 3.1.0. I'm using Fedora 24, I first tried using gcc that comes with Fedora (gcc (GCC) 6.2.1 20160916 (Red Hat 6.2.1-2)). I have also tried with GCC 6.2.0, compiled on my machine.

I'm using cmake with the following parameters:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -DBUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -DINSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -DWITH_TBB=ON -DWITH_V4L=ON -DINSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -DWITH_QT=ON -DWITH_OPENGL=ON -DWITH_OPENCL=ON -DWITH_EIGEN=ON -DWITH_OPENEXR=ON
```

`cmake` runs fine and then I run `make`. Doesn't matter the commbination of OpenCV version and gcc version, the result is the same:

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/6.2.0/bits/stl_algo.h:59:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/6.2.0/algorithm:62,
                 from /home/dmelo/proj2/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/base.hpp:55,
                 from /home/dmelo/proj2/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core.hpp:54,
                 from /home/dmelo/proj2/opencv/modules/highgui/include/opencv2/highgui.hpp:46,
                 from /home/dmelo/proj2/opencv/build/modules/highgui/precomp.hpp:45:
/usr/local/include/c++/6.2.0/cstdlib:75:25: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
 #include_next <stdlib.h>
                         ^
compilation terminated.
```

Is anyone else experiencing this? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Try by disabling pre-compiled headers (the variable is easy to find if you open cmake-gui)

Comment: It worked. Add ``-DENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF`` as parameter for ``cmake`` did the job. Would you please post it as an answare, so that I can mark it as correct?

Comment: how to do this..i din understood.i am a newbie..its kinda urgent..please help..Thanks..

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Try by disabling pre-compiled headers, either from cmake-gui or using the command line parameter

```
-DENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF
```

Comment: You use cmake to build OpenCV. On the command line, add the parameter described on the answer:

`cmake -DENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF`

Comment: This was the command that worked for me :

cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_CUDA=ON -D WITH_CUDNN=ON -D WITH_CUBLAS=ON -D WITH_TBB=ON -D OPENCV_DNN_CUDA=ON -D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON -D CUDA_ARCH_BIN=6.1 -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=$HOME/opencv_contrib/modules -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF -D HAVE_opencv_python3=ON -DENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF -DCUDA_NVCC_FLAGS=--expt-relaxed-constexpr ..

Answer (score 8):

Compiling from zip package (opencv-2.4.11) did not work for me but
the latest version* from [github repo](http://github.com/opencv/opencv) gave me a successful build on ubuntu 17.04

```
git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
cd opencv
mkdir mybin
cd mybin
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -DENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF -DWITH_FFMPEG=OFF ..
make
sudo make install
```

**Update:** You might want to do `git checkout 3.4` after `git clone` because the master branch has many new changes since I wrote this

Note: ffmpeg is deprecated and optional so I have used `WITH_FFMPEG=OFF` flag
**Update:** I could build with ffmpeg on 18.04, used `WITH_FFMPEG=ON` flag. Latest ffmpeg should work with 17.04 as well. Comment down if you were successful!

*OpenCV commit id cca99bf8249387da9f79be8d549b2d49e39a0289

Additional info:
Dependencies I installed before compiling-

```
build-essential cmake git libgtk2.0-dev pkg-config python-dev python-numpy libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libtiff-dev libdc1394-22-dev libtbb2 libtbb-dev
```

Hope this helps someone in future!

Answer (score 4):

I am on Manjaro Linux and this problem do exists on my system because of `TBBConfig.cmake` file which is a part of `Intel-TBB` library and contains modification to path of `include` folder path at line 56:

```
set_target_properties(TBB::${_tbb_component} PROPERTIES
                                  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../../../include")
```

While `-DENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF` was already off in my case and didn't fix the issue, it seems that this flag `-DCMAKE_NO_SYSTEM_FROM_IMPORTED=ON` fixes it.

Answer (score 4):

For archlinux distro like Manjaro the flags `-D ENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF` and `-D CMAKE_NO_SYSTEM_FROM_IMPORTED=ON` fixed it with success.

I also got problems with `blas` and `cblas` during compilation. 
I linked `cblas` by adding `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS=-lcblas`.

Answer (score 3):

For me this:

```
[ 33%] Building CXX object 
/home/rdp/ffmpeg-windows-build-helpers/sandbox/cross_compilers/mingw-w64-x86_64/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++    @CMakeFiles/Transform360.dir/includes_CXX.rsp -std=c++11  -O3 -DNDEBUG   -o CMakeFiles/Transform360.dir/Library/VideoFrameTransform.cpp.obj -c /home/rdp/ffmpeg-windows-build-helpers/sandbox/win64/transform360_git/Transform360/Library/VideoFrameTransform.cppCMakeFiles/Transform360.dir/Library/VideoFrameTransform.cpp.obj
In file included from /home/rdp/ffmpeg-windows-build-helpers/sandbox/cross_compilers/mingw-w64-x86_64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/8.2.0/ext/string_conversions.h:41,
                 from /home/rdp/ffmpeg-windows-build-helpers/sandbox/cross_compilers/mingw-w64-x86_64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/8.2.0/bits/basic_string.h:6391,
                 from /home/rdp/ffmpeg-windows-build-helpers/sandbox/cross_compilers/mingw-w64-x86_64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/8.2.0/string:52,
                 from /home/rdp/ffmpeg-windows-build-helpers/sandbox/cross_compilers/mingw-w64-x86_64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/8.2.0/stdexcept:39,
                 from /home/rdp/ffmpeg-windows-build-helpers/sandbox/cross_compilers/mingw-w64-x86_64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/8.2.0/array:39,
                 from /home/rdp/ffmpeg-windows-build-helpers/sandbox/cross_compilers/mingw-w64-x86_64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/8.2.0/tuple:39,
                 from /home/rdp/ffmpeg-windows-build-helpers/sandbox/cross_compilers/mingw-w64-x86_64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/8.2.0/bits/stl_map.h:63,
                 from /home/rdp/ffmpeg-windows-build-helpers/sandbox/cross_compilers/mingw-w64-x86_64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/8.2.0/map:61,
                 from /home/rdp/ffmpeg-windows-build-helpers/sandbox/win64/transform360_git/Transform360/Library/VideoFrameTransform.h:18,
                 from /home/rdp/ffmpeg-windows-build-helpers/sandbox/win64/transform360_git/Transform360/Library/VideoFrameTransform.cpp:14:
/home/rdp/ffmpeg-windows-build-helpers/sandbox/cross_compilers/mingw-w64-x86_64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/8.2.0/cstdlib:75:15: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
 #include_next <stdlib.h>
               ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

meant "edit CMakeFiles/Transform360.dir/includes_CXX.rsp and replace -isystem with -I" hint from [here](https://github.com/OxfordSKA/OSKAR/issues/10)

Comment: I got a similar error. What is frustrating is that there is no clear logical path to me what C++/cmake is doing here. stdlib.h is provided by glibc for me, so why does GCC via C++ try to want to use its own header which then breaks?