# CMake fails to compile with GCC 6.3

Tags: gcc, cmake

CMake fails to bootstrap with GCC 6.3 installed.
The tests checking for a C++ compiler fail due to not finding stdlib.h and iostream.h which were removed in GCC 5.

Output of Bootstrap.cmk/cmake_bootstrap.log:

```
Try: cc
Line: cc  cmake_bootstrap_39083_test.c -o cmake_bootstrap_39083_test
----------  file   -----------------------

#ifdef __cplusplus
# error "The CMAKE_C_COMPILER is set to a C++ compiler"
#endif

#include<stdio.h>

#if defined(__CLASSIC_C__)
int main(argc, argv)
  int argc;
  char* argv[];
#else
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
#endif
{
  printf("%d%c", (argv != 0), (char)0x0a);
  return argc-1;
}

------------------------------------------
1
Test succeeded
Try: g++
Line: g++  -DTEST1 cmake_bootstrap_39083_test.cxx -o cmake_bootstrap_39083_test
----------  file   -----------------------

#if defined(TEST1)
# include <iostream>
#else
# include <iostream.h>
#endif

class NeedCXX
{
public:
  NeedCXX() { this->Foo = 1; }
  int GetFoo() { return this->Foo; }
private:
  int Foo;
};
int main()
{
  NeedCXX c;
#ifdef TEST3
  cout << c.GetFoo() << endl;
#else
  std::cout << c.GetFoo() << std::endl;
#endif
  return 0;
}

------------------------------------------
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6.3.0/ext/string_conversions.h:41:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/basic_string.h:5402,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6.3.0/string:52,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6.3.0/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6.3.0/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6.3.0/iostream:39,
                 from cmake_bootstrap_39083_test.cxx:3:
/usr/include/c++/6.3.0/cstdlib:75:25: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
 #include_next <stdlib.h>
                         ^
compilation terminated.
Test failed to compile
Try: g++
Line: g++  -DTEST2 cmake_bootstrap_39083_test.cxx -o cmake_bootstrap_39083_test
----------  file   -----------------------

#if defined(TEST1)
# include <iostream>
#else
# include <iostream.h>
#endif

class NeedCXX
{
public:
  NeedCXX() { this->Foo = 1; }
  int GetFoo() { return this->Foo; }
private:
  int Foo;
};
int main()
{
  NeedCXX c;
#ifdef TEST3
  cout << c.GetFoo() << endl;
#else
  std::cout << c.GetFoo() << std::endl;
#endif
  return 0;
}

------------------------------------------
cmake_bootstrap_39083_test.cxx:5:23: fatal error: iostream.h: No such file or directory
 # include <iostream.h>
                       ^
compilation terminated.
Test failed to compile
Try: g++
Line: g++  -DTEST3 cmake_bootstrap_39083_test.cxx -o cmake_bootstrap_39083_test
----------  file   -----------------------

#if defined(TEST1)
# include <iostream>
#else
# include <iostream.h>
#endif

class NeedCXX
{
public:
  NeedCXX() { this->Foo = 1; }
  int GetFoo() { return this->Foo; }
private:
  int Foo;
};
int main()
{
  NeedCXX c;
#ifdef TEST3
  cout << c.GetFoo() << endl;
#else
  std::cout << c.GetFoo() << std::endl;
#endif
  return 0;
}

------------------------------------------
cmake_bootstrap_39083_test.cxx:5:23: fatal error: iostream.h: No such file or directory
 # include <iostream.h>
                       ^
compilation terminated.
Test failed to compile
```

### Update:

The issue could be resolved changing the following line in cstdlib:

```
#include_next <stdlib.h>
```

To:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Comment: iostream.h is not needed, and your compiler/system is badly installed if you are missing stdlib.h.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error compiling OpenCV, fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40262928/error-compiling-opencv-fatal-error-stdlib-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: Maybe, but in this situation I couldn't even run CMake, because I couldn't compile it. The error source may be the same, but the solution "turn off precompiled headers" won't work.