# make: **all error 2 during opencv installation in ubuntu16.10

Tags: opencv, cmake

```
    [  8%] Generating test_precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_test_imgcodecs_Release.gch
    In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/ext/string_conversions.h:41:0,
             from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/basic_string.h:5402,
             from /usr/include/c++/6/string:52,
             from /home/vibha/OpenCV/modules/viz/include/opencv2/viz/types.hpp:49,
             from /home/vibha/OpenCV/modules/viz/include/opencv2/viz/vizcore.hpp:49,
             from /home/vibha/OpenCV/build/modules/viz/test_precomp.hpp:58:
/usr/include/c++/6/cstdlib:75:25: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
#include_next <stdlib.h>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
modules/viz/CMakeFiles/pch_Generate_opencv_test_viz.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'modules/viz/test_precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_test_viz_Release.gch' failed
make[2]: *** [modules/viz/test_precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_test_viz_Release.gch] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:3080: recipe for target 'modules/viz/CMakeFiles/pch_Generate_opencv_test_viz.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/viz/CMakeFiles/pch_Generate_opencv_test_viz.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/ext/string_conversions.h:41:0,
             from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/basic_string.h:5402,
             from /usr/include/c++/6/string:52,
             from /usr/include/c++/6/stdexcept:39,
             from /usr/include/c++/6/array:39,
             from /usr/include/c++/6/tuple:39,
             from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_map.h:63,
             from /usr/include/c++/6/map:61,
             from /home/vibha/OpenCV/build/modules/viz/precomp.hpp:49:
/usr/include/c++/6/cstdlib:75:25: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
#include_next <stdlib.h>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
modules/viz/CMakeFiles/pch_Generate_opencv_viz.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'modules/viz/precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_viz_Release.gch' failed
make[2]: *** [modules/viz/precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_viz_Release.gch] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:3186: recipe for target 'modules/viz/CMakeFiles/pch_Generate_opencv_viz.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/viz/CMakeFiles/pch_Generate_opencv_viz.dir/all] Error 2
[  9%] Generating perf_precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_perf_imgcodecs_Release.gch
[  9%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_perf_imgcodecs
[  9%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_test_imgcodecs
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have installed build-essential package.
Also found stdlib.h present. 
But still I am getting this error.

I am installing opencv 3.2 on ubuntu 16.10 from https://github.com/milq/milq/blob/master/scripts/bash/install-opencv.sh

I am new to linux, so please tell me if I am doing anything wrong.(I have followed all the instructions in the above site as it is..)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error compiling OpenCV, fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40262928/error-compiling-opencv-fatal-error-stdlib-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: I found a solution in [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40262928/error-compiling-opencv-fatal-error-stdlib-h-no-such-file-or-directory].

Answer (score 0):

"You might have missed prerequisite for OpenCV 3.2.0"

```
[compiler] sudo apt-get install build-essential
[required] sudo apt-get install cmake git libgtk2.0-dev pkg-config libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev
[optional] sudo apt-get install python-dev python-numpy libtbb2 libtbb-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libtiff-dev libjasper-dev libdc1394-22-dev
```

**REFER:**

[Tutorial OpenCV Linux](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html)

[linuxfromscratch opencv](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/cvs/general/opencv.html)