# Facing issue installing openCV 2.4.9 on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, installation, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to install openCv on ubuntu 18.0
I have followed steps of this [blog](https://elementztechblog.wordpress.com/2014/07/28/installing-opencv-2-4-9-in-linux/)

But when I run this command

> make

it throws the following error

```
[ 57%] Built target opencv_perf_ocl
[ 57%] Built target opencv_nonfree
[ 57%] Built target opencv_perf_nonfree
[ 58%] Built target opencv_test_nonfree
[ 58%] Building CXX object modules/contrib/CMakeFiles/opencv_contrib.dir/src/chamfermatching.cpp.o
/home/knoldus/opencv-2.4.9/modules/contrib/src/chamfermatching.cpp: In member function ‘void cv::ChamferMatcher::Matching::computeDistanceTransform(cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, float, float, float)’:
/home/knoldus/opencv-2.4.9/modules/contrib/src/chamfermatching.cpp:969:30: error: the compiler can assume that the address of ‘annotate_img’ will never be NULL [-Werror=address]
             if (&annotate_img!=NULL) {
                              ^
/home/knoldus/opencv-2.4.9/modules/contrib/src/chamfermatching.cpp:1016:34: error: the compiler can assume that the address of ‘annotate_img’ will never be NULL [-Werror=address]
                 if (&annotate_img!=NULL) {
                                  ^
/home/knoldus/opencv-2.4.9/modules/contrib/src/chamfermatching.cpp: In member function ‘cv::ChamferMatcher::Match* cv::ChamferMatcher::Matching::localChamferDistance(cv::Point, cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, cv::ChamferMatcher::Template*, float)’:
/home/knoldus/opencv-2.4.9/modules/contrib/src/chamfermatching.cpp:1111:25: error: the compiler can assume that the address of ‘orientation_img’ will never be NULL [-Werror=address]
     if (&orientation_img!=NULL) {
                         ^
/home/knoldus/opencv-2.4.9/modules/contrib/src/chamfermatching.cpp:1111:5: warning: nonnull argument ‘orientation_img’ compared to NULL [-Wnonnull-compare]
     if (&orientation_img!=NULL) {
     ^~
/home/knoldus/opencv-2.4.9/modules/contrib/src/chamfermatching.cpp: In member function ‘void cv::ChamferMatcher::Matching::computeDistanceTransform(cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, float, float, float)’:
/home/knoldus/opencv-2.4.9/modules/contrib/src/chamfermatching.cpp:1016:17: warning: nonnull argument ‘annotate_img’ compared to NULL [-Wnonnull-compare]
                 if (&annotate_img!=NULL) {
                 ^~
/home/knoldus/opencv-2.4.9/modules/contrib/src/chamfermatching.cpp:969:13: warning: nonnull argument ‘annotate_img’ compared to NULL [-Wnonnull-compare]
             if (&annotate_img!=NULL) {
             ^~
cc1plus: some warnings being treated as errors
modules/contrib/CMakeFiles/opencv_contrib.dir/build.make:158: recipe for target 'modules/contrib/CMakeFiles/opencv_contrib.dir/src/chamfermatching.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [modules/contrib/CMakeFiles/opencv_contrib.dir/src/chamfermatching.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2974: recipe for target 'modules/contrib/CMakeFiles/opencv_contrib.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/contrib/CMakeFiles/opencv_contrib.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:151: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Why do you want to install such an old version of opencv. Even opencv 4 is available now.

Comment: Actually, right now I am working on a project which uses opnCv of this version. So i have to download the same version. I can't upgrade it to latest version

Comment: Take a look [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/65548/cmake-error-at-cmakeopencvdetectcxxcompilercmake/)

Comment: @Christoffer Thanks it worked. But now I am facing another issue while running make command.

Comment: @MaheshChandKandpal Related issue and answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40262928/error-compiling-opencv-fatal-error-stdlib-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: @Christoffer Thanks you have helped a lot. Now facing another issue. Did google found the same error but not found any solution.

Comment: Which bindings are you interested in?

Comment: @TA I didn't understand what exactly you are asking? I just want to install openCV

Comment: @MaheshChandKandpal are you using it with java/python/c++?

Comment: @TA I will use it for scala. But as it generated to bytecode so i can say java.

Comment: Then I would highly recommend just getting the ready build jar via maven. There are some repositories that contain the 2.x version. It is a big pain to build OpenCV from scratch in general.

Comment: @TA actually I have almost finished. It is the last step that's why I am giving it a try. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @MaheshChandKandpal I think you can fix it with this patch [here](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/opencv/blob/f24/f/opencv-2.4.12.3-gcc6.patch) but I'm not sure..

Comment: @Christoffer Thanks man. It worked. You can give this suggestion in the answer so that I could appreciate your effort by giving uptovte.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Installing old versions of opencv can cause a lot problems as stated in this question (check comments).

- Solution for Cmake errors regarding detection of CXXCompiler can be
  found [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/65548/cmake-error-at-cmakeopencvdetectcxxcompilercmake/)
- Solution for `fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory` can
  be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40262928/error-compiling-opencv-fatal-error-stdlib-h-no-such-file-or-directory)
- Solution for the make error stated in the latest edition of the
  question can be found in the patch [here](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/opencv/blob/f24/f/opencv-2.4.12.3-gcc6.patch)

Comment: While running my application, I failed run time error
undefined symbol: _ZN2cv8imencodeERKSsRKNS_11_InputArrayERSt6vectorIhSaIhEERKS5_IiSaIiEE

Do you have any idea regarding this?