# How to reproduce #include_next compile time error?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a library that could be compile on windows, And now i need to compile on WSL (*Debian 9.5*). But i get a confusing compile error:

```
/usr/include/c++/6/cstdlib:74:15
    #include_next <stdlib.h>
No such file or directory.
```

I try to change `INCLUDEPATH` variable (which i use *QMake*) but that make no sens. And i couldn't reproduce this error message on another project. How this could be happened ? and how could fix it ?

> **Specification**:
>   - *OS*: Debian 9.5 on WSL (Windows 10)
>   - *Compiler*: GCC 6.3.0
>   - *C++ Standard*: C++17
>   - *Include Paths*: `/usr/include` | `/usr/local/include` | `/usr/include/c++/6/`

Comment: What Debian packages did you install ?? Why are you using such an ancient version of [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) - in 2020 you should use [GCC 9](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-9/) since GCC 6 is obsolete.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, Did you know anything about old stable projects that run on old system ?, And we have no permission to change it.

Comment: Then  that should go into your question, which I downvoted because it lacked important information (what Debian packages do you use). Also notice the GCC6 has [very incomplete C++17 support](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx17). Recent versions of GCC have better C++17 support. My opinion is that you should *ask for permission* to update your compiler, providing a *technical argumentation* for that

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, You are right sorry, Unfortunately we couldn't take that permission and Fortunately it compile with that compiler option.

Comment: I want to encourage everyone to be kind regarding downvotes on this question because 1) there is a language barrier, 2) learning occurred, 3) a new user, and 4) it's already been closed and marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is on another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40262928/error-compiling-opencv-fatal-error-stdlib-h-no-such-file-or-directory).

Which is to disable precompiled headers.

```
-DENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF
```